# Looping inside async/await in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, loops, async-await

With `Async / Await` how do I loop over `MOVIES` (array of strings) so I can do the `search()` call once for every item, store the resulting object and end up with an array called `TORRENTS`?

```js
const TorrentSearchApi = require('torrent-search-api');
const fs = require('fs');

const DATA = fs.readFileSync('./movies.json');
const MOVIES = JSON.parse(DATA);

TorrentSearchApi.enableProvider('1337x');

(async () => {
  let array = [];
  let torrent;

  async function search() {
    try {
      // Here: How do I loop over 'MOVIES' so I can the interpolate that value as `${movie}` and push the result to array?
      torrent = await TorrentSearchApi.search(`${movie} 1080`, 'Movies', 1);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }

    return array;
  }
  // for each 'movie' in 'MOVIES' there should be one item in the 'TORRENTS' array now
  const TORRENTS = await search();
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Array.prototype.map()` on `MOVIES` and map every movie `string` to an awaited `Promise`, then `await` on a `Promise.all()` to continue once all `Promise`s are resolved and you've got all your torrents.

```js
(async () => {
  async function search() {
    try {
      // return value will be a Promise
      return await TorrentSearchApi.search(`${movie} 1080`, 'Movies', 1);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      // we're not returning anything in case of an error, so the return value will be `undefined`
    }
  }

  const TORRENTS = await Promise.all(
    MOVIES
      .map((movie) => search(movie))
      .filter((torrentPromise) => torrentPromise !== undefined) // here we filter out all the searches that resulted in an error
  );
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that `MOVIES` is an `<array>` and `${movie}` is a `<string | number>` value:

```
try {
  MOVIES.map(async movie => {
   torrent = await TorrentSearchApi.search(`${movie} 1080`, 'Movies', 1);
   array.push(torrent);
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

Comment: It will not let me `push` unless I wrap in `async`, but I'm not sure if I should nest `async`